# workbox in laravel - service worker activated but offline not working

Tags: laravel, service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I have a `laravel` project which I like to use `workbox` to generate the service worker for my app.

So I installed `workbox-cli`, the run `workbox wizard` and I get:

```
//workbox-config.js
module.exports = {
  "globDirectory": "public/",
  "globPatterns": [
    "**/*.{json,css,ico,svg,ttf,php,js}"
  ],
  "swDest": "public/sw.js"
};
```

which when run `workbox generateSW`, I will get:

```
//public/sw.js
importScripts("https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.4.1/workbox-sw.js");

self.__precacheManifest = [
  {
    "url": "content/1/manifest.json",
    "revision": "5cd897bcd50eab43f4e1502f17b86cb9"
  },
  //... and others

].concat(self.__precacheManifest || []);
workbox.precaching.suppressWarnings();
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {});
```

After that, I register `sw.js` in my `app.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("document ready: ");
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('./sw.js')
      .then(function(registration) {
        console.log("Service Worker Registered", registration);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Service Worker Failed to Register", err);
      })
    }
//...
})
```

When launch the page, I can see `sw.js` registered and activated in Application tab. And I check the cache storage also with all the files I want to cache. But somehow when I change to offline, I still cannot get the cached content to display.

I tried the same code(everything above) with just simple 1 page `html` with 1 `js`, and everything works fine. In the console, I can even see debug message from `workbox`:

[image]

But I did not get that in my `Laravel` app.
I suspect the `ImportScript` in `Laravel` somehow not working but I am not sure how to debug this.

Comment: do you have solution ?

Comment: after weeks of trying, i think that will not work with `laravel` because it seems to me the content is dynamically. however, i changed my mindset. for those pages that I want to cache, to something more static(not using blade, just normal html), then it will work.

Comment: I see. so it has something to do with the html file right ? since we never really get the html file, we cannot cache it ?

Comment: @punk73 At least that is what I am thinking. Hopefully someone with better understanding of this can give some solutions on this soon.